# pass the message variable out of the async def in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot that detects spam and deletes the message, it works like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global cont, msg
    msg = 0
    cont += 1
    msg = message.author
```

the variable `cont` counts every message and resets every 1 second, and to detect spam, I did this:

```
if cont > 6:
    print(f'spam from {msg}')
    cont -= 1
```

now to delete the message, I would need to delete the message, which is out of the `async def` statement, so, I need to pass the variable, at first I tried to do this

```
var=message
```

but the problem is that when you make a new variable in discord.py, it is a `int`, but for it to work, I need it to get it to the class `discord.message.Message`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

you will have to store message each time when a user sends a message.
and then match the new message with the old one.
so create a list of users and their messages:

```
messages = {
    users = [
    ]
}
```

and when a message is received, append to list:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    user = message.user.id
    msg = message.content
    users = messages['users']:
    for i in users:
        if i['id'] = user:
            i['msgs'].append(msg)
            count = 1
            for j in i['msgs']:
                if j = msg:
                    count += 1
            if count > 3:
                message.author.send("you are spamming")
        else:
            config = {"id": user, "msgs": [msg]}
            users.append(config)
```

*I typed it directly here, so there maybe bugs, contribute to the answer to improve it.*

another better way of handling spam is to use [**discord-anti-spam**](https://pypi.org/project/Discord-Anti-Spam/)
it's usage is pretty simple:

```
from discord.ext import commands
from AntiSpam import AntiSpamHandler

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
bot.handler = AntiSpamHandler(bot)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"-----\nLogged in as: {bot.user.name} : {bot.user.id}\n-----")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    bot.handler.propagate(message)
    await bot.process_commands(message)

bot.run("Bot Token")
```

read it's [**documentation**](https://dpy-anti-spam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?) for more details on changing it's moderation level.